# Updating part of a stateful widget

Tags: flutter, stateful

i'm very new to Flutter.
I have a stateful widget. Every time i click a counter, the whole build function runs and the results are updated.
But is there a way to make it a stateless widget and update only the relevant part somehow so i could avoid rebuilding the screen?

I have a stateful widget. Every time i click a counter, the whole build function runs and the results are updated.
But is there a way to make it a stateless widget and update only the relevant part somehow so i could avoid rebuilding the screen?

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MaterialApp(
        home:Home(),
      ));
    }
    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
    }
    
    class _HomeState extends State {
    
      int long =  0;
    
      void increaseCounter(){
        setState(() {
          long++;
        });
      }
    
      void decreaseCounter(){
        if(long > 0) {
          setState(() {
            long--;
          });
        }
      }
    
      Text numberOfDeliveries(){
    
        return Text(
          '$long deliveries today',
          style: TextStyle(
            color:Colors.white,
            fontSize: 24.0,
          ),
        );
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title:Text('Deliveries'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child:Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32.0, horizontal: 0.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'Long',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 32.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child:
                            // is it possible to update this without running the whole build again?
                          numberOfDeliveries(),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32.0,  horizontal: 0.0),
                                color:Colors.blue[100],
                                child: FlatButton(
                                  onPressed: (){
                                    decreaseCounter();
                                  },
                                  child: Text('-'),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32.0,  horizontal: 0.0),
                                color:Colors.blue[500],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32.0,  horizontal: 0.0),
                                color:Colors.blue[900],
                                child: FlatButton(
                                  onPressed: (){
                                    increaseCounter();
                                  },
                                  child: Text('+'),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue[800],
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text('Bottom'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options. Try learning provider

Comment: What @Uni said is true. But if you are new to flutter, (in my own opinion) start with `setState` first. It will help you improved step by step. (Note: `setState` only available in `StatefulWidget`)